# How can I make my ExFAT partition unmount cleanly?

Tags: mount, fstab, fsck, unmounting, exfat

I've got Raspbian running on a Raspberry Pi 4 B.  I have a USB hard disk that I'm using with it.  The hard disk is a 1TB drive formatted with a single partition using ExFAT.  I've got `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed.  The problem is that every time I unmount the partition, when I run `fsck` on that partition, it gives me this warning:

```
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
```

That makes me nervous.  This happens no matter how the partition is unmounted.  It happens on shutdown and subsequent bootup, it happens on reboots, it happens if I just manually `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and `sudo mount /dev/sda1`

Here's some system information:

```
Linux rpi4b 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
exfat-fuse/stable,now 1.3.0-1 armhf [installed]
exfat-utils/stable,now 1.3.0-1 armhf [installed]
```

This is the line concerning the partition in my `/etc/fstab`.

```
UUID=BE1B-4EFA  /media/BE1B-4EFA      exfat   defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail  0       0
```

Why isn't my partition unmounting cleanly?  How can I make sure it does?

Comment: Did you ever figured this out? I'm suffering from the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and an ExFAT SSD disk :)

Comment: same. ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I also have the same problem, on an internal M.2 SSD drive that I'd initialized on a Mac, and then cleanly unmounted.  Now, when I mount it on my Mochabin (Linux version 5.4.163-00034-ga7e9e3c22288 (gti@ubuntu)), I get the same warning.  umount / mount doesn't solve the probelm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose issues with unmounting the volume you can run the following:

```
sudo -i
fsck.exfat /dev/sdc6
```

Once you determine the cause of the error, you can fix it with testdisk, though it looks like you may have to compile from source, as there is no binary for your platform.

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

https://github.com/cgsecurity/testdisk

Comment: I encountered the same issue the other day, & at first thought it was due to a failed drive beneath an LVM. (This was an old system that had been running for years with little modification or attention.) But first, for fits & giggles ran "fsck -y" as root on the drive; upon reboot, I found the problem was solved.